# ifstream not working in my code?

Tags: c++, ifstream

My code doesn't output the first 10 lines of main.cpp as I expected. Please tell me why. Thanks!

```
#include "TStack.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ifstream in("main.cpp");
    Stack<string> textlines;
    string line;
    while (getline(in, line)) {
        textlines.push(new string(line));
    }
    string* s;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << "1" << endl;
        if((s = (string*)textlines.pop())==0) break;
        cout << *s << endl;
        delete s;
    }


}
```

The following is the header.The following is the header.The following is the header.The following is the header.The following is the header.

```
#ifndef stackex_TStack_h
#define stackex_TStack_h

template <class T>
class Stack {
    struct Link{
        T* data;
        Link* next;
        Link(T* dat, Link* nxt): data(dat), next(nxt) {}
    }* head;

public:
    Stack() : head(0) {}
    ~Stack() {
        while(head)
            delete pop();
    }
    void push(T* dat) {
        head = new Link(dat, head);
    }

    T* peek() const {
        return head ? head->data : 0;
    }
    T* pop() {
        if(head == 0) return 0;
        T* result = head->data;
        Link* oldHead = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete oldHead;
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: I use Xcode by the way.

Comment: We have no idea how `Stack` works, so how can we tell you what is broken? Does it print the numbers `1` to `10` with nothing else? Or just `1` and then stop? Also, what's wrong with `std::vector<std::string>`? Or is the aim here to write `Stack`, and this is just a test case?

Comment: What is the return type of Stack.pop()? this is probably where the issue lies. I wouldn't mess with pointers here. Typically pop should return a value not a reference.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what it IS outputting? Any errors or what it is actually outputting would help. Also, as already mentioned, we need more information on how your stack class works.

Answer (score 2):

Ehm... that depends. What does `Stack` do? How many `"1"`s does it print - one or ten?

`Stack` looks weird anyway: why do you need to cast the `pop` if it's templated on `string`? I believe `pop` doesn't return what you think it returns.

**Edit**

I copied your code and I get 10 "1"s, with lines. I actually get the LAST 10 lines of the file, in reverse order (good exercise for you - figure it out, it makes perfect sense).

If you don't get any lines and only 1 "1", my guess is that the program doesn't find the file (the executable is executed from a different directory)

Try adding prints into the `getline` loop and see how many lines you actually read.

Comment: @user2166066 well - I copied your code and I get 10 "1"s, with lines. I actually get the LAST 10 lines of the file, in reverse order (good exercise for you - figure it out, it makes perfect sense)

Comment: Ok, so `pop` is returning a null pointer. Probably your `Stack` implementation is broken.

Comment: @BoBTFish Actually I think the program just doesn't find "main.cpp", because it worked fine for me.

Comment: I agree with this diagnosis... especially if you are using the build/run command in Xcode. Try using the absolute path as well and see if you get better results.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I now know last 10 lines reverse order should be answer. But I can't get the result. I also try replace "main.cpp" by "TStack.h", doesn't work. I dragged a .txt file in, doesn't work either. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: @user2166066 yes - you are probably not running in the right directory. You have the path wrong. Try replacing "main.cpp" with "c:\[whatever the path is]\main.cpp" **Edit** Great! Have fun debugging the reverse order :)

Answer (score 0):

Your stack suppose (I did not fully check if it is implemented correctly) to work on LIFO principle (Last Input First Output) as stack should work by definition. So you should not expect that first 10 pops will return first 10 lines, it returns last ones. So you either use FIFO container or pop stack until you get last 10 items in it (but still in reverse order).